# Sum ifs on on SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, calculated-columns, countif, sumifs

I currently have a sharepoint list for recording staff interaction on a daily basis. There are 15 staff, each has three different interaction types (Calls, Emails, messenger), so that's 45 records per day are filled out.

Columns I have are: Month, Agent, Interaction Type daily interactions (1-31) Total Interactions.

What I need to be able to do is a sumif or countif Month=October and Interaction Type =email then total interaction=sum of all emails for the 15 agents etc.

Comment: Forgot to add. Total Interactions is a calculated column sum of days 1-31 for each interaction type

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to create a view that groups by Month and Type, and under Totals uses Sum on your Interactions column. The headers will have a total count of items in their category, which will be your CountIf, and the Total will be your SumIf.

Comment: Hi Aron, That would mean 36 different views. I need to be able to discplay a list view showing in essence, a table with current Month on the left then the the 3 rows, Calls, Email, Messenger with the totals of all agents displayed as a single total.

Ideally Excel Services would be used but we dont have it on our version of SharePoint.

Comment: "Group By" is different than "Filtering". You would need 1 view to display the information you're seeking. Your question has changed, though: you want only the current month displayed?

Comment: Hi Aron, no, question hasnt changed, and I can set filters to auto calculate which month to display. However, I still need to be able to do a total count of a filtered column. ie, my column headings are Month, Interaction, Totals.
At the moment, witht he group by set on Interactions, I can see 4 rows of data, for my 4 test agents and their total interactions per agent. I want to be able to see a grant total of interactions without seeing the agents name so its a team total. I am unable to do this as the individual totals are calculated fields wjhich MOSS cannot add up.